# Permission denied for user in www-data group

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chmod

I have a development server running wordpress.  The wordpress files are owned by www-data:www-data.

I wanted a quick way to be able to upload so I added my user to the www-data group and then did a chmod 775 -R for the plugins and themes folder.

I am still unable to upload files.  PHPStorm gives me a "permission denied" error.  The directory has rwx for group so why can't I write files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this from a shell prompt? Because I just did exactly what you said and it works fine for me. Why is PHPStorm trying to write with your user id? Wouldn't it use the web server's user id?

If it is using your user id, try restarting it to pickup the changes.

Comment: I just realised.  Some folders were owned by root which was causing the issue.